# Email validation not working in flutter display message even if email address is correct

Tags: regex, validation, email, flutter

In this code, the empty-email validation works but email-type validation does not work. Email-type validation still displays the "Invalid Email" message if a valid email address is inserted.

```
new TextFormField(
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Email'
      ),
      validator: (value){
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Email is required';
        }
        if(!value.contains(r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$')){
          return 'Invalid Email';
        }
        return null;
      },
    )
```

The line that is potentially erroneous is:

```
if(!value.contains(r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$'))
```

Comment: Added relevant tags, as it is an email-validation question.

Comment: As is common for ad hoc email regexes, yours will reject many valid email addresses, and accept many invalid ones. Don't roll your own.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/validation_textformfield

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can match the Regular Expression by using `hasMatch` method of `RegExp`

Try this

```
   Pattern pattern = r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
   RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
   if (!(regex.hasMatch(value)))
      return "Invalid Email";
```

If you want to use `.contains` of `String` you can pass a `RegExp` object as argument

```
if (!(value.contains(regex)))
     return "Invalid Email";
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/validation_textformfield

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [email_validator](https://pub.dev/packages/email_validator) package from `pub.dev` to validate your e-mail address.

Add dependencies to your `pubspec.yaml` file

```
dependencies:
   email_validator: ^1.0.6
```

Import the `email_validator` to the `.dart` file

```
import 'package:email_validator/email_validator.dart';
```

Check the form validation

```
        Form(
              autovalidate: true,
               child :  TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: ("email"),
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (!EmailValidator.validate(value)) {
                        return 'Please enter a valid email';
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                )
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/validation_textformfield

Answer (score 0):

> you can simple use this RegExp

```
validator: (input){
                           bool emailValid = RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+").hasMatch(input ?? "");
                            if(emailValid == true)
                            {
                              return null;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                              return "Email id should be valid";
                            }
                           
                           },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 validator: (val) {
                        if (RegExp(
                              r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$',
                            ).hasMatch(val) &&
                            !emailExists) {
                          return null;
                        } else {
                          if (emailExists == true) {
                            return "Email already exists, please sign in";
                          } else {
                            return "Please provide a valid email";
                          }
                        }
                      },
```

for emailExists, add this line:

```
bool emailExists = false;
```